# What are the common package names for pin spacing in multiples near 50-mils?

Tags: pcb, layout, component-selection, footprint

I'm looking for component package names that are known to provide conductors on (nearly) 50-mil spacing so it fits well on a [50x50mil SMT protyping board](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00LLQ1Q46).

I know SOIC are 50-mil, and even SOT-223 is close enough to work (0.090 =~ 0.050x2).  I tried [Wikipedia's list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrated_circuit_packaging_types) but they don't always provide pin spacing for the package list.

What naming conventions might indicate 50-mil spacing?  Is there a list somewher that you could point me toward?

(I would like to filter Digikey/Mouser for the footprint sizes that would fit well when chosing a component.)

Comment: I think that Wikipedia page pretty much gives you the list of pitches, from 0,1" to 0,5" and even some 0,25". I don't believer there was ever a naming convention to indicate a particular pitch. Earlier packages had larger pin spacing and subsequent pitches just evolved with the arrival of denser components etc...